# Android | Allow different libs version in the same project

Tags: android, apk, version, aar, libs

tl;dr

My question is: how can my app use those "Some AAR lib" and each of those libs can use it's own version of the "Base code lib"?

So I'm struggling with this subject quite some time now.
I have this project structure as shown below:

My application is consuming aar libs that each is made of some base code,
those libs have different versions of this base code (as aar dependency).

the problem is:
When I add both libs to my project, somehow it compiles the APK file with the most recent version of the "Base Lib" which is v2.0 and when I need to use some parts and functionality of the left "Some AAR Lib" that have the base code in version 1.2, the app crashes because it can't find the method or some parts of the code because it uses version 2.0 and version 1.2 is excluded from the APK dependencies.

Those libs are different modules that are NOT related to each other.
As they only uses the same base the provides with helper methods and some functionality in order to write it once, they are entirely different modules and have different purpose.

Thanks for everyone who tries :)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It seems completly unuseful and wrong use two different versions of same library inside a single project.

How do you think it would like to work? If both 1.2 and 2.0 AAR has "*org.example.test.methodTest()*", how you would like to choose which lib version to use? It's not possibile because libraries "lives" inside packageNames (now "namespaces") and if two libraries shares same packagename/namespace, one lib overwrites the other one.

It seems you're at the beginning of programming journey......maybe you have to understand basic things about Libraries in any language you want, because it's the same in each programming language.

===UPDATE AFTER ILLUSTRATION UPDATED===

If there are two Modules, instead of 2 Libs:

- each Module should have its own "*implementation('...')*" so each Module can use same packageName of another one without ruin something even if it is using a different library version
- each Module now needs a namespace and all "assets/resources/libs" have to stay PRIVATE inside each Module. An App (the "parent") MUST NOT directly use Lib 1.2 or 2.0 methods but have to call a Module's method an THIS last one "chooses" if use 1.2 or 2.0 version based on its Module "implementation(...)" declarations.
- If you need App call 1.2 or 2.0 methods directly, then you have to specify its own "implementation(...)" of that Library.

Comment: There is many different examples for that that are working. I just can't find those. I've added some more info about those versions and aar libs. Also do know that my coding journey began at 2014 :)

Comment: Also updated illustration